# Estimates in Hölder spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, holder-spaces

Let $u,v\in C^{2,\alpha}\left(\overline{\Omega}\right)$. Proof that there exists a constant $C>0$ so that
\begin{equation}
\|\Delta v\left(|\nabla v|^2-|\nabla u|^2\right)\|_0\leq C\left(\|u\|_2+\|v\|_2\right)^2\|v-u\|_2.
\end{equation}
I've tried to solve this problem but the best I could do is to estimate this quantity by
\begin{equation}
 \|\Delta v\left(|\nabla v|^2-|\nabla u|^2\right)\|_0\leq\|v\|_2
\cdot\left(\||\nabla u|\|_0+\||\nabla v|\|_0\right)\||\nabla(v-u)|\|_0,\end{equation}
although I don't know if it's correct. If this estimate was correct, I just have to prove that if $u\in C^{2,\alpha}\left(\overline{\Omega}\right)$ then
\begin{equation}
\||\nabla u|\|_0\leq\|u\|_2,
\end{equation}
but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: What's $||\cdot||_2$? $C^2$ norm?

Comment: With $\|\cdot\|_k$ i mean the usual norm in $C^{k,\alpha}$.

Comment: Doesn't $\| \cdot \|_2$ have the norm of the derivative built into it?